# Configuring Apache with Puppet and Vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, puppet

I'm using Vagrant and Puppet for the first time in a project and I keep running into an issue.

I've used PuPHPet as a starting point, and I have the following snippet in my default.pp manifest:

```
class { 'apache': }

apache::dotconf { 'custom':
  content => 'EnableSendfile Off',
}

apache::module { 'rewrite': }

apache::vhost { 'awesome.dev':
  server_name   => 'awesome.dev',
  serveraliases => [
],
  docroot       => '/var/www',
  port          => '80',
  directories => [ { path => '/var/www/', allow => 'from all', allow_override => ['All'] }   ],
  env_variables => [],
  priority      => '1',
}
```

When I run it, I always get the following error:

```
warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Invalid parameter directories at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:46 on node precise32
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests && puppet apply --verbose --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' default.pp --detailed-exitcodes || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

Line 46 is the end of the apache::vhost rule. I want to set it to allow override using htaccess, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. Can anyone see what the issue is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PuPHPet uses the Example42 Apache Puppet module, see the README file. This module doesn't have a directories parameter in the vhost resource:

https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet-apache/blob/master/manifests/vhost.pp#L100

Only the Puppet Labs Apache module has a directories parameter, but it's a different module:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/vhost.pp#L25

You can however use the directory parameter in Example42's module similarly to the example which can be found in the vhost resource:

```
#  apache::vhost { 'my.other.site':
#    docroot                    => '/path/to/docroot',
#    directory                  => '/path/to',
#    directory_allow_override   => 'All',
#  }
```

Comment: Just a note that as of a few months ago I switched PuPHPet over to the puppetlabs-apache module so this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: It is still correct for all those who use the example42 module, and quite useful.